# How to Block-Read a File with Python

Tags: python, io, blocking

I'm rather new in this Python-area and want to read from a file that is written by another programme while that is running. So my script should read a line as soon as it is written by the other programme.

Here is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import datetime
import os
import select
import sys

FILENAME = "/home/sjngm/coding/source/python/text.log"
with open(FILENAME, "r", encoding = "utf-8", errors = "ignore") as log:
    print("blocks: " + str(os.get_blocking(log.fileno())) + " / fd: " + str(log.fileno()) + " / " + str(log))
    while True:
        os.pread(log.fileno(), 1, 0)
        sel = select.select([log], [], [], 60000.0) #[0]
        line = log.readline().replace("\n", "")
        if line:
            print(line)
        else:
            print("-" + str(datetime.datetime.now()), end = "\r")

        # do something interesting with line...
```

text.log (for now it's just a regular text file and no other process accesses it):

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

*It doesn't matter if there is a `\n` at the end of the last line or not*

Output:

```
[sjngm@runlikehell ~]$ python ~/coding/source/python/test.py 
blocks: True / fd: 3 / <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/sjngm/coding/source/python/text.log' mode='r' encoding='utf-8'>
line 1
line 2
line 3
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sjngm/coding/source/python/test.py", line 16, in <module>
    line = log.readline().replace("\n", "")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
KeyboardInterrupt
[sjngm@runlikehell ~]$ uname -a
Linux runlikehell 4.14.53-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jul 3 17:59:17 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[sjngm@runlikehell ~]$
```

So it says that blocking is enabled. After printing the three lines the script keeps going and prints the current time constantly without any pause.

It actually should pause at `pread()`, `select()` or `readline()`. Or as a matter of fact at any other command that I just don't know of.

How do I make this work?

*Note that I don't want to pipe the file to the script as I want to use curses later on and its `getch()` wouldn't work in such a scenario.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this isn't a common situation. What I'm doing now is this:

```
import subprocess

with subprocess.Popen([ "tail", "-10000f", FILENAME ], encoding = "utf-8", errors = "ignore", universal_newlines = True, bufsize = 1, stdout = subprocess.PIPE).stdout as log:
    line = log.readline()
```

In other words I'm opening the pipe **in** the script rather than pipeing something **to** the script. The buffering seems to be done in `tail` in connection with `Popen`'s parameter `bufsize`. `encoding` and `universal_newlines` allow `readline()` to read a string rather than a byte-array (see [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) for more info on that).

System's `stdin` is now still available and `curses` works nicely with keyboard/mouse events.